# How to set up NGINX WordPress Multisite on MAMP?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-config, multisite, mamp-pro

I have been trying to create an Nginx environment on MAMP Pro for a WordPress Multisite with subdirectories. I was able to do majority of the steps to create the WordPress multisite however I realized that Nginx does not use htaccesss and instead its required nginx.conf file to be updated per their documentation at: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/nginx/. I believe this is preventing me from accessing my second sub-site wp-admin dashboard and causing my second sub-site to return 404 (Not Found) errors for every external link and stylesheet (I already checked database site urls and blog urls were set correctly).

I've attempted to make the changes but it could also be I am doing it wrong as this would be my first time attempting to do this.

So I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of which directives would need to be added and where? I'm attaching a copy of the MAMP nginx.conf for reference and I believe some directives can also be added via the MAMP GUI dashboard so I'll be attaching a screenshot of what I'm seeing for reference.

Nginx.conf

```
MAMP_ngx_http_image_filter_module_MAMPload_module "modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";
MAMP_ngx_http_perl_module_MAMPload_module "modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so";
MAMP_ngx_http_xslt_filter_module_MAMPload_module "modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so";
MAMP_ngx_mail_module_MAMPload_module "modules/ngx_mail_module.so";
MAMP_ngx_stream_module_MAMPload_module "modules/ngx_stream_module.so";

MAMP_User_Directive_MAMPuser                        MAMP_User_MAMP MAMP_Group_MAMP;
worker_processes            auto;

events {
    worker_connections      1024;
}

http {
    include                 /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type            text/html;
    gzip                    on;
    gzip_types              text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
    
    sendfile                on;
    keepalive_timeout       65;

    # access_log            "/Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_access.log";
    error_log               "MAMP_NginxErrorLog_MAMP";

    server_names_hash_bucket_size  128;

    # Enables or disables stapling of OCSP responses by the server. Example:
    #ssl_stapling on | off;

    # Enables or disables verification of OCSP responses by the server
    #ssl_stapling_verify on | off;

    server {
        listen              MAMP_Port_MAMP default_server;
        listen              MAMP_SSL_Port_MAMP default_server ssl;
        ssl_ciphers         'aNULL';
        ssl_certificate     "/Applications/MAMP/conf/server/default.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/Applications/MAMP/conf/server/default.key";

        return 444;
    }

    server {
        listen              MAMP_Port_MAMP;
        server_name         localhost;

        root                "MAMP_Localhost_DocumentRoot_MAMP";

        location / {
            index            MAMP_Localhost_DirectoryIndex_MAMP;
        }
    
        location ~* /MAMP([^-].*)$ {
            root             "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO";
            index            index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files        $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpLocalhost_MAMP.sock;
                fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
        }

        location ~* /phpMyAdmin(.*)$ {
            root             "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO";
            index            index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files        $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpLocalhost_MAMP.sock;
                fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
        }

        location ~* /phpMyAdmin5(.*)$ {
            root             "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO";
            index            index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files        $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpLocalhost_MAMP.sock;
                fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
        }

        location ~* /phpPgAdmin(.*)$ {
            root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
            index            index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files        $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpLocalhost_MAMP.sock;
                fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
        
        location ~* /phpLiteAdmin(.*)$ {
            root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
            index            index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files        $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpLocalhost_MAMP.sock;
                fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
        
        location ~* /adminer(.*)$ {
            root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
            index            adminer.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files        $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpLocalhost_MAMP.sock;
                fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
        
        location /icons {
            alias /Applications/MAMP/Library/icons;
            autoindex on;
        }
        
        location /favicon.ico {
            alias /Applications/MAMP/bin/favicon.ico;
            # log_not_found off;
            # access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpLocalhost_MAMP.sock;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }

        # location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$ {
        #     expires          30d;
        # }

        # location = /robots.txt {
        #     allow all;
        #     log_not_found off;
        #     access_log off;
        # }

        # location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        #     allow 127.0.0.1;
        #     deny all;
        # }

        # location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        #     return 403;
        # }

        location /nginx_status {
            stub_status      on;
            access_log       off;
            allow            127.0.0.1;
            deny             all;
        }
    }

    MAMP_VirtualHost_iteration_begin_MAMP
    server {
        listen              MAMP_IP_Port_MAMP;
        server_name         MAMP_VirtualHost_ServerName_MAMP;
        MAMP_VirtualHost_ServerAliases_MAMP

        root                "MAMP_VirtualHost_DocumentRoot_MAMP";

        location / {
            try_files       MAMP_Try_Files_MAMP;
            index           MAMP_VirtualHost_DirectoryIndex_MAMP;
            autoindex       MAMP_VirtualHost_AutoIndex_MAMP;
            MAMP_VirtualHost_Allow_MAMP
            MAMP_VirtualHost_Deny_MAMP
            MAMP_LocationCustom_MAMP
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpHost_MAMP.sock;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        MAMP_VirtualHost_AdditionalCustom_MAMP
    }
    MAMP_VirtualHost_iteration_end_MAMP

    MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_iteration_begin_MAMP
    server {
        listen              MAMP_SSL_IP_Port_MAMP ssl;
        server_name         MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_ServerName_MAMP;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_ServerAliases_MAMP

        root                "MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_DocumentRoot_MAMP";
        # access_log          "/Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_ssl_access.log";
        error_log           "/Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_ssl_error.log";

        ssl_certificate     "MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_Certificate_MAMP";
        ssl_certificate_key "MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_CertificateKey_MAMP";
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_OnlyAllowTLS_MAMPssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_OnlyAllowTLS_MAMPssl_ciphers         'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
        MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_OnlyAllowTLS_MAMPssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_OnlyAllowTLS_MAMPadd_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

        location / {
            try_files       MAMP_Try_Files_MAMP;
            index           MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_DirectoryIndex_MAMP;
            autoindex       MAMP_VirtualHost_AutoIndex_MAMP;
            MAMP_VirtualHost_Allow_MAMP
            MAMP_VirtualHost_Deny_MAMP
            MAMP_LocationCustom_MAMP
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_phpMAMP_PhpHost_MAMP.sock;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        MAMP_VirtualHost_AdditionalCustom_MAMP
    }
    MAMP_SSLVirtualHost_iteration_end_MAMP
}

# DONT REMOVE: MAMP PRO nginx.conf template compatibility version: 23
```

[image: MAMP GUI dashboard]

I've attempted to copy and paste the code from this link to various locations in the nginx.conf file and on the MAMP app GUI PER: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/nginx/#wordpress-multisite-subdirectory-rules. But I feel like I'm not adding it correctly as nginx is something I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I find this so much better than MAMP: https://localwp.com/